# ajax GET json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to access this JSON data: http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=2661886&callback=listPlaces&style=long&noCacheIE=1400498525471&get_param=value

The reponse is formated like this

```
listPlaces(
{
totalResultsCount: 21,
geonames: [
{
countryId: "2661886",
adminCode1: "02",
countryName: "Sweden",
fclName: "country, state, region,...",
countryCode: "SE",
lng: "15.33333",
fcodeName: "first-order administrative division",
toponymName: "Blekinge",
fcl: "A",
numberOfChildren: 5,
name: "Blekinge",
fcode: "ADM1",
geonameId: 2721357,
lat: "56.33333",
adminName1: "Blekinge",
population: 152315
}
```

I use this ajax method to access the data, but my console.log(data) shows nothing.
I don't know how to handle the fact that the response starts with listPlaces( and then json-data inside that.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=2661886&callback=listPlaces&style=long&noCacheIE=1400498525471',
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.geonames, function (index, element) {
            //Todo
        });
    }
});
```

What am i dong wrong?

Comment: Maybe a crosssite scripting error? Do you use a browser with a dev console, did you check there?

Comment: does it actually get to the success function?

Comment: remove &callback=listPlaces

Comment: Remove callback worked, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove callback attribute from url

It should be

```
http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=2661886&style=long&noCacheIE=1400498525471
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Ggv/)**

Answer (score 2):

this api is used like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function listPlaces(data){
        alert(data.totalResultsCount);
        ...
    }
</script>
<script src="http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=2661886&callback=listPlaces&style=long&noCacheIE=1400498525471"></script>
```

here callback `listPlaces` should be a function which receives JSON data as parameter
and must be declared before calling script
and for ajax remove the callback variable from url

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `callback` parameter to the API, remove it (`&callback=listPlaces`) from the URL-

http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=2661886&style=long&noCacheIE=1400498525471&get_param=value